# Healthcheck JSON monitoring

Tags: monitoring, web

I have a web service that has a healthcheck endpoint that returns some JSON about the status of various subsystems. Is there a (preferably free) service I can use to monitor this JSON, and alert me (by email, preferably) if something changes? Ideally it's got a bit of intelligence in it (or some particular format I can put the data in) so that it's got a bit of intelligence.

Although I could build it myself, I'd rather use a 3rd party service.

Currently I use [Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com) which can do "keyword exists at endpoint", but I'm at the point where something more sophisticated would be useful, but basically the same otherwise.

Comment: For over a decade, I have been very happy with https://www.changedetection.com/ which monitors web pages for change. I can't think why it wouldn't also work for a RETS API like yours. Please give it a try & let us know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated api monitoring service at https://www.runscope.com/, but it is not free.